# WHY "code or data emission to undeclared segment"?

Tags: assembly, x86

when I run it,the vscode always remind me "code or data emission to undeclared segment"?

```
buff 1 equ,1000h
buff2 equ,2170h
start: mov SI, offset buff2
LEA DI,BUFF1
MOV CX,100H
CYCLE:MOV AL[SI]
MOV [DI],AL
INC SI
INC DI
LOOP CYCLE
ANOTHER: MOV DI,OFFSET BUFF1
MOV CX,100
CLD
AGE: SCASB
DEC CX
JZ FIN
JNZ AGE
JMP OVER
FIN: MOV[DI],20H
CMP CX,0
JNZ AGE
OVER: RET
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `buff 1 equ,1000h` looks like invalid syntax, with a space and a `1` after `buff` before the `equ`.  IDK exactly what MASM would say about it, but maybe this.  You didn't say what line your error message was on.

Comment: You have to put your code and data inside a SEGMENT directive.

Comment: I'm sorry.....I am a green hand about assembly, can you show me the example?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what it is exactly your MASM is complaining about. I'd point out that it is unclear whether you are trying to use a text mode or a video mode.

At any rate, per [this](https://electronicsdesk.com/assembler-directives.html#:%7E:text=Definition%3A%20Assembler%20directives%20are%20the%20instructions%20used%20by,instructions%20that%20control%20the%20operation%20of%20the%20assembler), you assign a text/video mode and the service BIOS interrupt as follows:

```
DATA SEGMENT
mov ax, 13h ; example
                
int 10h       ; signal to enact video svc BIOS interrupt (for video mode, 
                ; char/str out, rd/wrt pxls in gfx mode, etc.)
DATA ENDS
```